# web.config not writable on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, web-config

I'm hosting wordpress on Windows Azure platform, and currently, I have an empty web.config that I need to configure rules to allow pretty permalinks. For some reason, the web.config doesn't seem to be writable, and I've tried to change it manually in FileZilla, but it says command can not be understood. So, what should I do?

Comment: are you trying to update the web.config ON THE SERVER?  That's not a great plan because your changes won't be persistent should the server recycle, hardware fail, etc.  Also is this an Azure Web Site or an Azure Cloud Service?

Comment: I created it with the 'From Gallery' section, so I think it's an Azure web site. I'm not trying to update the web.config. My old web.config is gone somehow, so I need to re-create it. But neither the empty web.config or the configured web.config wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify the web.config in a way which could cause problem to your application. What happens is that whenever the web.config is change it triggers a  notification about this change which cause your IIS host process to recycle. After this notification IIS host process restarts by reload the updated/modified web.config and if you have made wrong modification your application will not run properly.

In your situation when you suggested web.config is "gone" it is actually not gone, it is there but not visible in your FileZilla due to some ACL issue (not sure what the reason for it) as I have seen same issue. Trying creating a new FTP session and see if the web.config is visible again.

Another option for you is to download the full site locally and then after editing locally you can publish it back with updated content and the site will be back as expected.

Comment: Problem is, I already modified the existing web.config. Now the entire site is broken with internal server error, whether I'm adding new web.config, update new rules to the existing web.config, or remove the existing web.config.

Comment: In this situation re-deploying your application will solve your problem.